# Question about Michael Silverstein and Linguistics Ideology

Tags: language-change, sociolinguistics

I'm trying to understand Silverstein approach to ideological change. To my understanding he claims speakers are aware of the social and power relations reflected in the language usage and structure, and alter it according to ideological changes.

When speaker change his language usage due to ideological change, does that mean he necessarily has to be consciously aware of the power relations reflected by the previous usage, or his new ideologies can alter the language usage in a more 'subconscious' level?

Comment: references,  please?